# Testclass for PageReference

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I tried to write a testclass, but this is very complicated.
Below you will find my short code for testing, but the coverage is just 36%. How can I test the PageReference?

Could you tell me how is the best way to code a test code. This is not very clear for me. Rules?

```
public void CHECK_URL() {
    CHECK_URL = ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl();
    IF (CHECK_URL != NULL) {
        IF(CHECK_URL.contains('TEST1')) { TEST1 = 1; }
        IF(CHECK_URL.contains('TEST2')) { TEST2 = 1; }
    }
}

public PageReference TEST1_click() {
    TEST1_result = TEST1_value / 3.35 * 100;
    return new PageReference('/apex/Parameter_info');   
}

public PageReference TEST2_click() {
    TEST2_result = TEST2_value * 3 / 100 * TEST2_time;
    return new PageReference('/apex/Parameter_info');   
}
```

**Test**

```
@isTest 

private class Parameter_Test {

    static TestMethod void TEST1_test() {       
        Parameter_class PC = new Parameter_class();        
        PC.TEST1_value = 1000;

    }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do really? This may be a bit of an X-Y problem. Pagereference is meant to set the context and you evaluate the returned URL or lack thereof. Your code does not even get to the point of your question as you have not even executed a single method that you posted. Maybe that is where you should start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For covering a Pagereference method, you first need to instantiate your class, using which you can call the Pagereference method.

I tried to write a psuedo code to explain it more.

Main class:

```
public class MyClass {
    public Decimal TEST1_value { get; set; }
    public Decimal TEST1_result { get; set; }
    public MyClass() {}
    public PageReference TEST1_click() {
        TEST1_result = TEST1_value / 100;
        return new PageReference('/apex/Parameter_info');   
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest private class MyClassTest {
    static TestMethod void TEST1_test() {       
        MyClass objClass = new MyClass();        
        objClass.TEST1_value = 1000;

        // start test
        Test.startTest();
        PageReference pr = MyClass.TEST1_click();

        // validate the functionality using asserts
        System.assertEquals('/apex/Parameter_info', pr.getUrl());
        System.assertEquals(10, objClass.TEST1_result    );
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul, unfortunately I get the error that the variable MyClass.Test1_result (in my case Parameter_class.TEST1_result) does not exist.

Comment: Ah, I made a typo. it should be [Instance of the class].method name. updated the answer